# Uploading a PDF File to Azure Blob Storage using REST API & C# (Without using any AZURE STORAGE SDKs)

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-rest-api

I am trying to upload a file in to an Azure Storage Container using REST API, without using any SDKs.

Reason for not using the Azure.Storage.Blobs SDK is, it has a dependency on .netstandard2.0 and some of the DLLs referred by the SDK is not compatible when the project runs .NET Framework 4.6.1. I tried assembly binding redirect in the config and didn't workout well (System.ValueTuple.dll reference issue).

Hence i am trying to re-write my Upload code using C# and REST API without the SDK.

Here is code that i am trying

```
public class AzureRestApi
{
        private string _x_ms_client_request_id = string.Empty;

        private string _x_ms_date = string.Empty;

        public string AzureStorageAccountName { get; set; }

        public string AzureStorageAccessKey { get; set; }

        public string BlobSaveFolder
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string X_MS_DATE
        {
            get
            {
                return _x_ms_date;
            }
        }

        public string X_MS_VERSION
        {
            get
            {
                return "2019-12-12";
            }
        }

        public string BaseURI
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/", AzureStorageAccountName);

            }
        }        

        public AzureRestApi()
        {
            //Date and GUID should be same that is used to create the key signing string and the one that is being sent in the 
            //header of REST api requests.
            _x_ms_date  = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
            _x_ms_client_request_id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        public bool UploadBlobToContainer(string filePath, string containerName)
        {
            bool isUploaded = false;

            try
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                long contentLength = fileInfo.Length;
                long range = contentLength - 1;
                string method = "PUT";
                string contentType = "application/pdf";
                string blobName = fileInfo.Name;
                string blobURI = BaseURI + containerName + "/" + blobName;
                string xmsHeader = $"x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:{X_MS_DATE};\nx-ms-version:{X_MS_VERSION}";
                string resHeader = $"/{AzureStorageAccountName}/{containerName}/{blobName}";

                if (WebRequest.Create(blobURI) is HttpWebRequest request)
                {
                    request.Method = method;
                    request.ContentType = contentType;
                    request.ContentLength = contentLength;
                    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
                    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", X_MS_DATE);
                    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", X_MS_VERSION);                    
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetAuthorizationHeader(method, xmsHeader, resHeader, request));

                    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        byte[] fileContents = null;
                        using (FileStream fs = fileInfo.OpenRead())
                        {
                            fileContents = new byte[fs.Length];
                            fs.Read(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                            fs.Close();
                        }
                        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                    }

                    if (request.GetResponse() is HttpWebResponse response)
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                            isUploaded = true;
                        else
                            isUploaded = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.LogException(ex);
            }
            return isUploaded;
        }

        private string GetAuthorizationHeader(string method, string xmsHeader, string resHeader, HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            string strToSign = $"{method}\n\n\n{request.ContentLength}\n\n{request.ContentType}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{xmsHeader}\n{resHeader}";

            string signatureString = GetHashedString(strToSign, AzureStorageAccessKey);

            string authorizationHeader = string.Format(
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                 "{0} {1}:{2}",
                 "SharedKey",
                 AzureStorageAccountName,
                 signatureString);

            return authorizationHeader;
        }
}
```

Code to invoke the Upload function

```
string storageName = "MyDefaultStorage";
            
string containerName = "MyDefaultContainer";
            
AzureRestApi restApi = new AzureRestApi()
{
    AzureStorageAccountName = storageName,
    
    AzureStorageAccessKey = "MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY", 
};

restApi.UploadBlobToContainer("E:\\UploadFiles\\UploadDocument1.pdf", containerName);
```

Exception is thrown while executing this line
 `if (request.GetResponse() is HttpWebResponse response)`

Exception Message: **The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.**

I tried to simulate this request using PostMan and got this error message

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'RW1ACnL1aYqtSnJeHhV2694Ek95Olnf+V3Eup4Jt5ng=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT



461804


application/pdf






x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Wed, 12 Aug 2020 19:30:20 GMT
x-ms-version:2019-12-12
/MyDefaultStorage/MyDefaultContainer/UploadDocument1.pdf'
```

I tried the answers given in these links and it works if the file is a text file, but fails when tried with a pdf

[Azure rest api put blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829911/azure-rest-api-put-blob)
[REST Api to Azure blob storage using Access key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774567/rest-api-to-azure-blob-storage-using-access-key)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Raghunathan S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you added an extra semicolon in this code:

```
string xmsHeader = $"x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:{X_MS_DATE};\nx-ms-version:{X_MS_VERSION}";
```

please change to this：

```
string xmsHeader = $"x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:{X_MS_DATE}\nx-ms-version:{X_MS_VERSION}";
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: If my answer helps you, you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank your @Steve Zhao. It worked perfectly. Don't know how I missed this simple detail. Once again.. Thanks.